# using WITH clause for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I was planning to use the `WITH` clause with PostgreSQL, but it doesn't seem to support the command. Is there a substitute command?

What I want to do is with one query select several sub-resultsets and use parts of the sub-resultsets to create my final `SELECT`.

That would have been easy using the `WITH` clause.

**UPDATE**:

Opps! I discovered that I misunderstood the error message I got; and pgSQL does support WITH.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what is wrong with it?

Comment: Check the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL supports common-table expressions (`WITH` queries) in version 8.4 and above. See [common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) in the manual.

You should really include your PostgreSQL version, the exact text of the error message, and the exact text of any query you ran in your question. Where practical/relevant also include table definitions, sample data, and expected results.